# error: use of ‘auto’ in lambda parameter declaration only available with ‘-std=c++14’ or ‘-std=gnu++14’ and PCL errors

Tags: c++, lambda, auto, pcl

I am performing calibration using link "https://github.com/lixiny/handeye-calibration-ros".

When I run `catkin_make` under `src/ Handeye-Calibration-ROS`, it is giving me following error:

```
/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/common/impl/io.hpp:272:33: error: use of ‘auto’ in lambda parameter declaration only available with ‘-std=c++14’ or ‘-std=gnu++14’
```

and command `catkin_make` end with PCL error:

```
make[2]: *** [camera_driver/CMakeFiles/realsense2_driver.dir/build.make:76: camera_driver/CMakeFiles/realsense2_driver.dir/src/realsense2_driver.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2053: camera_driver/CMakeFiles/realsense2_driver.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j24 -l24" failed
```

I tried `CXXFLAGS=--std=gnu++14`, still same error.

In which file I need to change the value of C++?

Comment: What version of compiler do you use?

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0

Comment: Did you set your `CXXFLAGS` in the makefile?

Comment: No, where I have to set this?

Comment: Usually it's set somewhere at the beginning of the makefile of whatever you are building

Comment: Also watch out for the dashes, in your question you said you set `CXXFLAGS=--std=gnu++14`, im pretty sure thats should be `-std=gnu++14` or `-std=c++14` with just one dash

Comment: I set that in terminal

Comment: You shouldn't set the flag manually but use this instead: `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)`. After you declare your project name.

Comment: I tried `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)` / `set (CXXFLAGS=-std=gnu++14)` /`set(CXXFLAGS=-std=c++14)` under `makefile.cmake`. Getting same error

Answer (score 0):

According to [Cmake's site](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html), you can set the c++ standard using:

```cpp
set_property(TARGET tgt PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

If you want to modify the makefile itself, adding the c++ flag should produce a command that looks similar to:

```cpp
g++ -std=c++14(or gnu++14) main.cpp -o main
```

Comment: This didn't help. 
To confirm which file I need to modify.
CMakeLists.Txt file is lock. Under the build>CMakeFiles>Makefile.cmake, do I need to modify this file or some other

Comment: This should be going in CMakeLists.txt, i don't believe it would work if you put it in Makefile.cmake. Can you elaborate on what you mean by it being locked?

Comment: When I installed Handeye-Calibration-ROS, CMakeLists.txt is locked. I changed camera_driver, camera_transform_publisher, handeye_calib_marker CMakeList.txt file. I changed C++11 to C++14. After that package handeye_calib_marker, camera_transform_publisher passed, where camera_driver failed `Catkin build`